# articles with a word "special"

Tags: word-choice, difference, articles

I'm not sure which is the best expression of the three sentences below.

1. There is **special paper** that is strong against water.
2. There is **a special paper** that is strong against water.
3. There is **a kind of special paper** that is strong against water.

"paper" here is not a newspaper, a wallpaper, nor essay etc.
I heard that if there is a word "special," there should be an article like "a special dinner."

Comment: Perhaps "a special type of paper" would be best?
There is a difference in meaning between your sentences two and three.  #2 says that there is "a special paper that is strong against water", which may imply that there is only one of them, while "a kind of special paper" reveals that there can be more than one of these.

Comment: @myacorn Oh, I see!  Then, #1 is not correct here?  Thank you very much!

Comment: @myacorn Then is "a special type of paper" neutral between #2 and#3? How difficult it is!  Thank you so much!

Comment: **A special kind of paper** is better than **a kind of special paper**. _Special_ describes that particular type of paper (designed not to disintegrate when wet).

Comment: OP, none of your sentences are idiomatic. Nobody (to my knowledge) says "...is strong against water." (outside of card games or magic contexts). People say that things are "water-resistant" or you could go with what @KateBunting suggested.

Comment: @KateBunting Ah, I see! Thank you for your help again! I'm so grateful.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Oh, I didn't know that.. My post looks strange or funny:) I understand. thank you so much..!